# Issue with Microsoft HID Output Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hid

So i am creating this HID app, and for some reason, I am having issues with sending Output Reports. I tried the Microsoft way and it always gives me a  "The specified report type is not present" error. Can someone figure out what the problem is here?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BmTK.png)

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic;using System.IO;using System.Linq;using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;using Windows.Foundation;using Windows.Foundation.Collections;using Windows.UI.Xaml;using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;using Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice;using System.Diagnostics;using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;using Windows.Storage;using Windows.Storage.Streams;using Windows.UI.Core;using System.Threading.Tasks;using System.Text;


namespace TouchEncoderComms
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private HidDevice touchEncoder;
        private ushort vendorId;
        private ushort productId;
        private ushort usagePage;
        private ushort usageId;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        vendorId = 0x1658;
        productId = 0x0060;
        usagePage = 0xFF70;
        usageId = 0x0001;
        ConnectTouchEncoder();
    }

    private async void ConnectTouchEncoder()
    {
        string selector = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vendorId, productId);
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
        if (devices.Any())
        {
            touchEncoder = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(devices.FirstOrDefault().Id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            Debug.WriteLine("Touch Encoder Connected");
            InputReportsListener(touchEncoder);
            //SendOutputReport(touchEncoder);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: Touch Encoder not found!");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void InputReportsListener(HidDevice touchEncoder)
    {
        if(touchEncoder == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        touchEncoder.InputReportReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            HidInputReport inReport = args.Report;
            UInt16 id = inReport.Id;
            byte[] byteArray = { };
            string flag = string.Empty;
            Debug.WriteLine("Byte: " + inReport.Data.GetByte(4));
            for (uint i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                byteArray.Append(inReport.Data.GetByte(i));
                flag += ' ' + inReport.Data.GetByte(i).ToString() + ' ';
            }
            //Debug.WriteLine("Input Report Received: " + flag);
        };
    }

    private async void SendOutputReport(HidDevice touchEncoder)
    {
        if (touchEncoder == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        HidOutputReport outReport = touchEncoder.CreateOutputReport();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

        DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
        dataWriter.WriteBytes(buffer);
        outReport.Data = dataWriter.DetachBuffer();
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

}

CreateOutputReport() function causes the error saying:

```
System.Exception: 'The data is invalid.
The specified report type is not present'
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Sorry for that. I added my whole code. thanks

Comment: Basically the problem is, the HidOutputReport outReport = touchEncoder.CreateOutputReport(); line produces an error that's mentioned above. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This probably means that the device's HID report descriptor either does not define an OUTPUT report item, or else defines multiple OUTPUT report items each identified by a REPORT_ID  - in which case you would have to specify a valid report ID on your call to CreateOutputReport()

Comment: It dows support receiving OutputReports and I tried a bunch of Report ID's but i think I'm missing some steps or something. Im attaching a link to the device documentation. Please can anyone help. link: https://1ec2c5e2-db6e-4512-8280-d031f845197a.filesusr.com/ugd/7db2d6_dc849fdd6f10404484e106fd0529f117.pdf ,       https://1ec2c5e2-db6e-4512-8280-d031f845197a.filesusr.com/ugd/7db2d6_ad202d7dc81f429b8786bee3364b6ef3.pdf  , https://1ec2c5e2-db6e-4512-8280-d031f845197a.filesusr.com/ugd/7db2d6_d7a1ca99bd2746229972d4664fea537c.pdf